# Evaluating negative one to a rational power (transformation of a Bessel function argument)

Tags: exponentiation, bessel-functions

The Handbook of Mathematical Functions gives the following relation for modified Bessel functions of the first kind:
$$I_\nu(\lambda z)=\lambda^{\pm\nu}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(\lambda^2-1)^k(\frac{1}{2}z)^k}{k!}I_{\nu\pm k}\left(z\right)$$
(A&S 9.6.51).

I am interested in the case $\lambda = -1,\ \nu = \frac{1}{6}$ (and my $z$ is a complex number). As $\left(\lambda^{2} - 1\right)^{k}$ reduces to $0$ for $k \ne 0$, I am actually dealing with
$$I_{\nu}\left(- z\right)=(-1)^{\pm\nu}I_{\nu}\left(z\right).$$

My problem lies in picking the correct form for $(-1)^{\pm\nu}$ between $e^{-i\pi\nu}$ and $e^{i\pi\nu}$. As $\nu$ is not an integer, they are obviously not equivalent. I can numerically check which one fits, but I would like to have a more robust argument than that.

Cheers

Comment: $I_\nu$ in general is a multivalued function best defined on the Riemann surface of the logarithm (on the universal covering space of $\mathbb{C}\setminus \left\{0\right\}$). There is no such thing as $-1$ on this surface. You can replace $-z$ by for example $ze^{\pi i}$ or $ze^{-\pi i}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. From [DLMF 10.25.2](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.25.E2),

$$\frac{I_\nu(z)}{I_\nu(-z)} = \frac{z^{\nu}}{(-z)^{\nu}}.$$

As $
\mathrm{ph}(-z) = \begin{cases}
\mathrm{ph}(z) + \pi & \text{if $\mathrm{ph}(z) \in (-\pi, 0]$} \\
\mathrm{ph}(z) - \pi & \text{if $\mathrm{ph}(z) \in (0, \pi]$}
\end{cases}
$,

$$
\frac{I_\nu(z)}{I_\nu(-z)} = \begin{cases}
e^{-i\pi\nu} & \text{if $\mathrm{ph}(z) \in (-\pi, 0]$} \\
e^{+i\pi\nu}  & \text{if $\mathrm{ph}(z) \in (0, \pi]$}
\end{cases}.
$$

Comment: You are missing something in one of the arguments because the ratio you wrote is just $1$.

Comment: Also, use the more modern reference http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.34.E1

Comment: @Gary Indeed. Fixed, thanks.